# Baptism in the Spirit

Tags: baptism, pneumatology, resource-request, ephesians

I'm trying to find a certain sermon of Martyn Lloyd Jones.   It contains a passage which is often quoted, but I'd like to find out in which sermon (or volume of sermons published by Banner of Truth) it is.

In this sermon he is talks about the *Baptism in the Spirit*, and says that some Christians believe they don't have to seek anything, because they received it when they were born again.   In other words They've got it all - there is nothing else to seek.    And he continues,  "If you've got it all, where is it?   If you've got it all, why are you so unlike the New Testament Christians?"

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). For more on what this site is all about, please see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394).

Answer (score 2):

It could be the sermon "[Spirit Baptism and Sanctification](https://www.mljtrust.org/sermons/spirit-baptism-and-sanctification/)."

Updated to add more information:

The reason I think this is the answer you are looking for is because I listened to it, and it appeared to be matching your criteria of:

- Baptism in the Spirit
- If you've got it all, where is it?
- If you've got it all, why are you so unlike the New Testament Christians?

Comment: I listened to it, and missed the "got it all" quote. I'll listen again, but does anyone have a timestamp for it?

Answer (score 0):

I am aware of this sermon but can't recall the source! A quote from J I Packer or John Stott I think 
"filled with the Holy Spirit but unfortunately I leak "

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). Do you think this is the approximate title of the sermon the questioner is looking for? Or are you referring to a different (perhaps related) sermon?